# Rmarkdown issues with plots (PDF output)

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, knitr

I’m using the following text at the beginning of my Rmarkdown to obtain a series of plots in PDF format. I have a customized function to create the plots, where the pvalues are plotted.

````
fontsize: 7pt
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_width: 20
    fig_height: 12
    fig_caption: yes
    toc: yes
  html_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    keep_md: yes
    theme: united
    toc: yes
date: '`r Sys.Date()`'

---


```{r setup, include = FALSE}
# knitr setup
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, dev = 'pdf')

```


```{r options, echo = FALSE}
# knitr options
  knitr::opts_chunk$set(comment = NA,
    fig.path = '01_models_figures_paper1/',
    results = 'markup',
    fig.width = 20,
    fig.height = 12,
    out.width = 20,
    out.height = 12,
    error = TRUE,
    tidy = FALSE,
    message = FALSE,
    warning = FALSE,
    echo = FALSE)
````

The problem is that the plots are correctly saved in PNG format (I tried it before saving them to PDF) and also if I zoom in the Plot Viewer in R Studio. This is the desired output:

[image: desired output with pvalues correctly displayed]

However, in the PDF exported files, the pvalues are all crushed and can’t be read at all:

[image: current output with pvalues incorrectly displayed]

I have played with all the parameters above with no luck, and have been reading as well, but wasn’t able to find anything to fix this.

Comment: Those are very large plots you are requesting.  The size is generally given in inches and the default is 7 inches, so you are requesting plots that are nearly 3 times normal in width.  Unless you are also requesting very large text (not 7pt, your default), it's going to look really tiny.  If that's not enough of a hint to figure this out yourself, please post a complete example, with the plot command, and someone should be able to tell you what's going wrong.

Comment: @user2554330 Thanks for your answer! Nothing was working, so in the end I recoded the whole function that does the plots (and finally it worked). Thanks.